# SSL Certificate Breaking User Login - ExpressionEngine

Tags: login, ssl

I have recently installed an SSL certificate on a website.

Unfortunately when enabled, members can not stay logged in. After the initial login, it logs you out every time the page refreshes.

Any idea on what could be causing this?

I am using this plugin
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/https-support

But i have also tried to achieve this using a rewrite in .htaccess

Comment: Sounds like a cookie domain issue. Try changing the admin session type to "Session-only" to see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a silly oversight after a long week of coding. Upon login the website redirected with a prefix of "www" where the rest of the site does not use this.

Fixed with WWW resolve in .htaccess